# Delegation Pattern in Swift 4 doesn't work! Can anyone explain the correct delegate pattern in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, delegation

Why doesn't this delegate pattern work? After selecting a Button in DelegateViewController I want to show the name property in the second ViewController (label outlet)

I have done the following steps:

1. Create protocol in "Boss" ViewController --> DelegateViewController
2. Assign my function to this protocol --> selectedButton
3. Create selectionButtonDelegate variable in DelegateViewController
4. In ViewController I have created a new instance of DelegateViewController()
5. In viewDidLoad I have then assigned the delegate of the instance equal self
6. I have created an extension with the function to passing the parameter

DelegateViewController:

```
import UIKit

protocol SelectionDelegate {
    func selectedButton(name: String)
}

class DelegateViewController: UIViewController {
    var selectionButtonDelegate: SelectionDelegate!

    @IBAction func bayernButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        selectionButtonDelegate.selectedButton(name: "Bayern")
    }

    @IBAction func dortmundButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        selectionButtonDelegate.selectedButton(name: "Dortmund")

    }
}
```

ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var selectedButton: UILabel!

    let model = DelegateViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        model.selectionButtonDelegate = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: SelectionDelegate {
    func selectedButton(name: String) {
        selectedButton.text = name

    }
}
```

Comment: You never display `model` from your `ViewController` so how can any of the buttons be tapped?

Comment: Delegate variable should be of optional type. And which controller comes first in stack ? DelegateController or ViewController ?

Comment: DelegateViewController is initial View Controller and comes first in stack.

Comment: @rmaddy my Buttons comes first in stack, can you explain me why I should display model from my ViewController? And how can I display model?

Comment: @iOSFats if  DelegateViewController is initial view controller then you will get selectionButtonDelegate = nil ,view controller should come first in stack then and only your delegate will be assigned

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation looks good, by looking at your code issues seems at

```
let model = DelegateViewController()
```

You are creating a new instance of `DelegateViewController`, but you must be clicking button from some other instance of `DelegateViewController` controller.

You probably need to get the correct instance of `model` instead of creating a new one OR should tap button from the newly created instance of View Controller.

Example: probably need to do something like

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

        if let navigationController = segue.destination as? DelegateViewController {
                selectionButtonDelegate = self = self
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You didn't assign selectionButtonDelegate to the current active DelegateViewController. Modify your code to access current instance of your DelegateViewController.

```
import UIKit

protocol SelectionDelegate {
    func selectedButton(name: String)
}

class DelegateViewController: UIViewController {

    static weak var shared: DelegateViewController!

    weak var selectionButtonDelegate: SelectionDelegate!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        DelegateViewController.shared = self
    }

    @IBAction func bayernButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        selectionButtonDelegate.selectedButton(name: "Bayern")
    }

    @IBAction func dortmundButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        selectionButtonDelegate.selectedButton(name: "Dortmund")

    }
}




import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var selectedButton: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        DelegateViewController.shared.selectionButtonDelegate = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: SelectionDelegate {
    func selectedButton(name: String) {
        selectedButton.text = name
    }
}
```

Also in most cases use weak before declaring delegate variables in Swift to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. This solution doesn't work for me. Is there anything I forgot?